# How to create glowing TextBox in WPF 4.0?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

I'm trying to create a text box, which would glow when focused.

All samples of how to do this I've seen so far were based on [OuterGlowBitmapEffect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752037%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) , and it appears that it [does not work in .net 4](http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/br/blend/thread/0424f7c5-90b3-449b-ad03-6ca29bf93fa0).

The recommendation in the second article is to use blur effect. I have no idea on how to use blur to get object's outer layer to glow without distorting the inner content of the object.

Ultimately, I'm hoping to create a text box, which would display glow up animation when focused, and the glow would slowly (1-2 seconds) fade after the control has lost focus.

Any ideas on what is the best way to do this in wpf 4.0?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try to get a decent "Glow-Effect" with `DropShadowEffect`. Here is an example

**Update**. A `TextBox` that starts to "glow" when focused and the "glow" slowly fades out for two seconds when it loses focus

[image]

```
<TextBox Text="Test">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Effect">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0"
                                      Color="Gold"
                                      Opacity="0"
                                      BlurRadius="8"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation To="1.0"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Effect).Opacity"
                                                 Duration="00:00:00"/>
                            </Storyboard>                                    
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation To="0.0"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Effect).Opacity"
                                                 Duration="00:00:02"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: That looks quite good! However how can I change the parameters <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0"
                                      Color="Gold"
                                      Opacity="0"
                                      BlurRadius="8"/> so that looks .... stronger? On my dark background I don't see it enough!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at 
http://wpfthemes.codeplex.com/
for a lot of good wpf theme ideas.  In particular, look at the theme for the textbox in Bureau Black.  I think what you want is actually what they use for their 'mouseover' attribute, but it should be easy to change that to a focused property instead.